# Getting mean value with multiple conditions(by columns) on pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I recently start using pandas but couldn't find the answer for this. (Maybe just because I don't know the query words to search)

Here's the example code

```
test1 = {'col1' : ["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"],
         'col2' : ["C","D","C","D","C","D","C","D"],
         'year' :["2012","2012","2013","2013","2012","2012","2013","2013"],
         'value' : [3,4,25,1,3,2,1,3]}
df_t = pd.DataFrame(data=test1)
df_t
```

In this DataFrame, I want to calculate mean of values with some condition.
col1 and col2 should be coupled(cuz it's trade data), so what I want to get is

```
Mean value of years of 'A(col1)', 'C(col2)'
Mean value of years of 'A', 'D'
Mean value of years of 'B', 'C'
...
etc.
```

As a result, I want a new DataFrame with 'col1', 'col2', 'mean_value' columns. But I think I can handle it if anyone teaches me how to get a mean value with those conditions above.

If anyone can enlighten me, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your interests!

Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `df_t.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['value'].mean().reset_index()`

```
  col1 col2  value
0    A    C   14.0
1    A    D    2.5
2    B    C    2.0
3    B    D    2.5
```

Comment: Genius! groupby can be used with list as an attribute!
Thank you so much life saver! You should have seen my enormous code to do the same thing (and yet couldn't succeeded).

Comment: glad to help, `goupby` is quite powerful, take a look here for more: https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/

Comment: Ah! And the great reference as well. Thank you again. This will be definitely helpful to me. Thank you again!
I've made great progress today thanks to your help :)